# JS: Counting Elements in Array -> Returning Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, count, reduce

I have an array which looks like this:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Peach', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach'];
```

Now I'm trying to count the containing elements to get a result which looks like this:

```
[
  ['Apple', 4],
  ['Peach', 2],
  ['Banana', 2],
  ['Pear', 1]
]
```

I was able to reduce it to a map. Like this:

```
fruits.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val, 1 + (acc.get(val) || 0)), new Map());
```

But I couldn't figure it out, how to create this array containing arrays.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: You can use spread syntax `console.log([...fruits.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val, 1 + (acc.get(val) || 0)), new Map())])`

Comment: wow ... i didn't know that you could use spread on a Map to get a result like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` has an [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) method that returns an iterator of key-value pairs. You can use `Array.from` if you require an array:

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Peach', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach'];

const fruitMap = fruits
  .reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val, 1 + (acc.get(val) || 0)), new Map());

// My preference because it's very clear what it does:
const fruitEntries = Array.from(fruitMap.entries());

// Other options:
/*
const fruitEntries = Array.from(fruitMap)
const fruitEntries = [...fruitMap];
*/


console.log(fruitEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `Object.entires()` method.

```js
fruits = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Peach', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach'];

var results = Object.entries(fruits.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = acc[val]+1 || 1;
  return acc;
},{}));
    
console.log(results);
```